# Taylor expansion with respect to a matrix argument

Tags: matrices, taylor-expansion

Suppose $J:\mathbb{R^{m \times n}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and that $\overline{X}, \delta X \in \mathbb{R^{m \times n}}$. What is the Tyalor series expension of $$J(\overline{X}+\delta X)$$?
 I'm looking for a similar expression as the following. Suppose $f:\mathbb{R^{m}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $. Then we can write
$$f(\overline{x}+\delta x)=f(\overline{x})+\nabla{f}(\overline{x})^T \delta x+\frac{1}{2} \delta x ^T \nabla{f}^2(\overline{x})\delta x  +....$$
However, for a scalar J with matrix argument, I clearly *cannot* write 
$$J(\overline{X}+\delta X)=J(\overline{X})+\nabla{J}(\overline{x})^T\delta X+....$$ because it does not make sense dimensionally. Should I use the Frobenius product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use the Frobenius product.

The gradient of the function in component form can be written
$$G_{ij} = \frac{\partial J}{\partial X_{ij}}$$
The Taylor expansion in component form is
$$\eqalign{
 dJ &= \sum_{ij} G_{ij}\,dX_{ij} \cr
}$$
or in matrix notation
$$\eqalign{
 J(X+dX) &= J(X) + G:dX \cr
}$$
To incorporate the Hessian (which is a 4th order tensor), you would write
$$\eqalign{
 J(X+dX) &= J(X) + G:dX + \frac{1}{2}dX:{\mathbb H}:dX \cr\cr
}$$
Extending this idea in another direction. If $X$ were a 3rd order tensor rather than a matrix, then you would have to use triple-dot products. The Taylor expansion would become
$$\eqalign{
 G_{ijk} &= \frac{\partial J}{\partial X_{ijk}}\cr
 dJ &= \sum_{ijk} G_{ijk}\,dX_{ijk} \cr
 J(X+dX) &= J(X) + G \therefore dX \cr
}$$

Comment: Hi @greg, could you please work out the term that involves the Frobenius inner product with the 4th order tensor? How can you explicitly write it to see the relative scalar form?

Comment: @Alberto The 4th order term looks like $$\tfrac{1}{2}\,dX:{\mathbb H}:dX
  = \tfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{\ell=1}^n
     dX_{ij}\,{\mathbb H}_{ijk\ell}\,dX_{k\ell}$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is it formally defined as you wrote with 2 inner products (i.e. with 2 "$:$")? I want to understand at a formality-level if it is right: if you remove the $ij$ indices and summation you can write  

$$\tfrac{1}{2}\,dX:{\mathbb H}:dX   = \tfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n   dX_{ij}\, \langle{\mathbb H}_{ij} ,dX \rangle_{F}$$

How can I see that also the remaining part is an inner-product ?